# Python RuntimeError freezes the whole Emacs!

Tags: python

This happens to me almost every time after i have broken an infinite loop (`RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while getting the str of an object`) in the Inferior Python process with `C-c C-c`. The whole emacs will get unresponsive, the only way will be `killall emacs` from terminal!
Maybe i can provide more information if it would be helpful.

Comment: It could be that the Python process is printing a lot of data before hitting that error, so Emacs is spending all its time reading?

Comment: Please provide a minimal setup to reproduce the error/problem.

Comment: It's not entirely clear what you're trying to do.  Please provide more details.

Comment: @Dan I was thinking of what information could i give about the spacial case, until the same thing happened in NO infinit loop and a very normal situation: i typed something in the Inferior Python, and hit Enter and Emacs freezed! Now i am lost!

Comment: Start emacs without your init file (`emacs -Q`).  Create a minimal setup with the Python-related packages.  Do you still get the same error?  Show us what you did to get to that problem.